# Move and re-size controls at run-time in winForms

Tags: c#, winforms, runtime, controls, formbuilder

I'm developing a dynamic form builder in c# winForms,
How can i make movable and re-sizable my controls(include pre-defined usercontrols) in winform for the end users?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31840/Move-controls-on-a-form-at-runtime

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: thanks, but i want to resize the controls also.

Comment: I believe you can take it as a good start and implement yourself

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/139930/A-simple-trick-to-resize-a-control-at-runtime

Comment: @masoud I strongly recommend WPF for this. winforms is a really old technology no one cares about, and is not recommended for any new projects.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx